How to avoid docker build warnings for LD_LIBRARY_PATH
I have a simple docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

When I do a simple docker build --check .
it shows this warning.
Usage of undefined variable '$LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
   2 | >>> ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
   3 |
   4 |
--------------------

What is the proper way to augment ENV variables like these without triggering warnings ? This is more of a general question on how do you know which ENV variable is declared or not in the base image and how to augment it without triggering a warning.

You probably know $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty in the base image, since it shouldn't be set  in normal use.  Can you just directly set it, or append to /etc/ld.so.conf, or put your shared libraries into a normal directory like /usr/local/lib?

This is more of a general question on how do you know which ENV variable is declared or not in the base image and how to augment it without triggering a warning


This is more of a general question on how do you know which ENV variable is declared or not in the base image

You can ask for your image to print its environment variables:
docker run --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 printenv

And since Dockerfile variables do have an interpolation syntax, you can use a default empty value, to cover the case where LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not defined:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"

